# How do I add X days to date and get new date?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, date

I  have Linux ( RH 5.3) machine

I need to add/calculate 10 days plus date so then I will get new date (expiration date))

for example

```
 # date 
 Sun Sep 11 07:59:16 IST 2012
```

So I need to get

```
     NEW_expration_DATE = Sun Sep 21 07:59:16 IST 2012
```

Please advice how to calculate the new expiration date ( with bash , ksh , or manipulate date command ?)

Comment: See also: [Stack Overflow: How to increment a date in a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18706823/4561887)

Answer (score 272, accepted):

You can just use the `-d` switch and provide a date to be calculated

```
date
Sun Sep 23 08:19:56 BST 2012
NEW_expration_DATE=$(date -d "+10 days")
echo $NEW_expration_DATE
Wed Oct 3 08:12:33 BST 2012
```

> ```
>   -d, --date=STRING
> ```

```
          display time described by STRING, not ‘now’
```

This is quite a powerful tool as you can do things like

```
date -d "Sun Sep 11 07:59:16 IST 2012+10 days"
Fri Sep 21 03:29:16 BST 2012
```

or

```
TZ=IST date -d "Sun Sep 11 07:59:16 IST 2012+10 days"
Fri Sep 21 07:59:16 IST 2012
```

or

```
prog_end_date=`date '+%C%y%m%d' -d "$end_date+10 days"`
```

So if `$end_date` = `20131001` then `$prog_end_date` = `20131011`.

Comment: Thank you!! Your examples should be in the GNU `date` info page!

Comment: On OS X when using the build-in date you will recieve an error. Use `brew install coreutils` to install  GNU's date function, `gdate`.

Comment: doesn't work: 
`$ docker run -it bash bash
bash-5.0# date -d "+10 days"
date: invalid date '+10 days'
bash-5.0# `

Comment: @ChristianBongiorno It does work, it has worked for years if not decades. The problem is almost certainly something to do with your environment.

Comment: `date; echo $BASH_VERSION; date -d "+10 days"
Wed 13 Feb 08:03:43 GMT 2019
5.0.0(1)-release
Sat 23 Feb 08:03:43 GMT 2019
`

Comment: `bash-5.0# date; echo $BASH_VERSION; date -d "+10 days" 
Wed Feb 13 17:24:47 UTC 2019
5.0.2(1)-release
date: invalid date '+10 days'
bash-5.0# 
`

Comment: @ChristianBongiorno like I said - something to do with your unnamed environment.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/500307/date-addition-in-bash-doesnt-work-in-docker/500313#500313

Comment: There you go then - it works as expected when using the correct (coreutils) version of date.

Comment: Is it possible to change the format after that? Like `$(date -d "+10 days" +"%Y")?

Comment: @CousinCocaine lifesaver. Someone should ask this question on the macOS overflow. Using the coreutils from brew makes all the scripts written over the years for linux usable on mac. But I need to replace the commands to add the g suffix.

Comment: @botenvouwer, check <https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/coreutils>. Add the gnubin to your PATH if you do not want to add the g prefix. `PATH="$(brew --prefix)/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"`

Answer (score 57):

You can use "+x days" as format string:

```
$ date -d "+10 days"
```

Comment: Note: you should be careful with the DST depending on the time zone. To see what I mean and the way to handle it correctly, see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/572420/307715)

Answer (score 40):

In Mac OS (and maybe other BSD distros):

```
$ date -v -1d
```

In order to get 1 day back date using date command:

```
$ date -v -1d
```

It will give (current date -1) means 1 day before .

```
$ date -v +1d
```

This will give (current date +1) means 1 day after.

Similarly below written code can be used in place of "d" to find out year,month etc.

```
y-Year
m-Month 
w-Week 
d-Day 
H-Hour 
M-Minute  
S-Second
```

Comment: This works for me on my mac, but not on our Gentoo servers.

Comment: Much better than the accepted answer, this allows for arbitrary date formats too in a single line.

Comment: this does not work on Ubuntu 15.10 or RedHat 6.6. I assume it does not work on RH5.3 either. Reason: '-v' and '-1d' are no valid switches for 'date'

Comment: This does appear to be a Unix/BSD syntax for `date`, which GNU's `date` (`gdate` on many BSDs) doesn't support.  GNU's `date` uses the syntax in the accepted answer.  Always remember: GNU's Not Unix!

Comment: @BaconBits - but if you're rms you can claim that because a lot of GNU util code has been ported to Linux that therefore "Linux **is** GNU". Except, of course, for the fact that GNU Hurd (FSF's Once-And-Future-OS) is just barely a thing. I suppose what pisses rms off is that while he spent his time pontificating, Linus spent his time writing code - which turns out to be proof positive that you're much more likely to create working software if you write code than if you pontificate. :-)

Comment: If you want to format AND do math on the datetime, you can do this `date -v +30M +'%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S'`

Answer (score 5):

I gave up on the GNU `date` command due to timezone confusion, and went to python.

```
python -c "import datetime, dateutil.parser; print((dateutil.parser.parse(\"$myDate\") + datetime.timedelta(days=10)).isoformat())"
```

Maybe it's overkill, but it's straightforward to read, understand and modify as needed.

`dateutil.parser.parse` is not part of the python standard library, so you have to `pip install dateutil`; alternatively you can use `datetime.datetime.fromisoformat`, but you need to be more careful about formats.

Answer (score 4):

As previous answers, you can use the `-d` switch like :

```
date -d "$myDate + 10 days"
```

**But you need to be careful with the time zone!**

An example of something that can go wrong :
If you want to get an interval for a day like [start of day, end of day] for the "8 march 2020" with the timezone at Montreal, where the DST start at 2:00:00 am, you could do

```
startDate=$(date --iso-8601=n -d "8 march 2020 00:00:00.000000001")
endDate=$(date --iso-8601=n -d "$startDate + 1 day")
```

but instead of

```
startDate → "2020-03-08T00:00:00,000000001-0500"
endDate   → "2020-03-09T00:00:00,000000001-0400"
```

you'll get 1 hour of the 9 march 2020

```
startDate → "2020-03-08T00:00:00,000000001-0500"
endDate   → "2020-03-09T01:00:00,000000001-0400"
```

To fix that, you could do the following :

```
# Returns the difference between two dates' local time offsets. E.g. : "3600" or "- 1800"
getLocalTimeOffsetDiffInSeconds() {

    # Get the offset in the following format: -0530 for -05h30min
    localOffset1=$(date -d "$1" +%z)
    localOffset2=$(date -d "$2" +%z)
    
    # Get the offset in seconds
    localOffsetInSec1=$(echo $localOffset1 | sed -E 's/^([+-])(..)(..)/scale=2;0\1(\2 * 3600 + \3 * 60)/' | bc)
    localOffsetInSec2=$(echo $localOffset2 | sed -E 's/^([+-])(..)(..)/scale=2;0\1(\2 * 3600 + \3 * 60)/' | bc)
    
    # Compute diff
    diffOffsetInSec=$(echo "$localOffsetInSec2 - $localOffsetInSec1" | bc)
    
    # Add a space between the sign and the value, so it can be used by the command "date".
    echo "$diffOffsetInSec" | sed -E 's/([+-])(.*)/\1 \2/'
}

  startDate=$(date --iso-8601=n -d "8 march 2020 00:00:00.000000001")
  endDate=$(date --iso-8601=n -d "$startDate + 1 day")
  
  # Fixes endDate if the DST changed between the two dates.
  
  dstDiff=$(getLocalTimeOffsetDiffInSeconds "$startDate" "$endDate")
  
  # dateFix will be a string to remove the dstDiff from the date in a format
  # that can be understood by the command "date". E.g. "3600 seconds" or "- 3600 seconds".
  dateFix=$(echo "$(echo "- $dstDiff" | bc | sed -E 's/([+-])(.*)/\1 \2/')")
  endDate=$(date --iso-8601=n -d "$endDate $dateFix seconds")
```