# date addition in bash doesn't work in docker

Tags: date

I have followed examples on numerous stack exchange websites and various other tutorial websites on how to do date math. I have tried linux (on containers) I get the exact same error:

```
$ docker run -it bash date -d '2014-11-19T15:40:30+10d'
date: invalid date '2014-11-19T15:40:30+10d'
bash-5.0# date -d  '+10 days'
date: invalid date '+10 days'
bash-5.0# date -d  '+10 d'
date: invalid date '+10 d'
bash-5.0# date -d  '2014-11-19T15:40:30+10 d'
date: invalid date '2014-11-19T15:40:30+10 d'
bash-5.0# date -d  '2014-11-19T15:40:30+10 days'
date: invalid date '2014-11-19T15:40:30+10 days'
bash-5.0# date -d  '2014-11-19T15:40:30 +10 days'
date: invalid date '2014-11-19T15:40:30 +10 days'
bash-5.0# date -d  '2014-11-19T15:40:30 +10 d'
date: invalid date '2014-11-19T15:40:30 +10 d'
```

bash version:

```
$ docker run -it bash bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.2(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-musl)
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

I've tried [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/45592/how-to-add-a-day-to-date-in-bash)
[This post](https://superuser.com/questions/45592/how-to-add-a-day-to-date-in-bash) and [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49053/linux-add-x-days-to-date-and-get-new-virtual-date) and even [this random website](https://linuxconfig.org/addition-and-subtraction-arithmetics-with-linux-date-command)

They can't all be wrong.

Comment: I tried all the combinations including yours. Updated the example. You can run the command yourself to try: `docker run -it bash date -d '2014-11-19T15:40:30+10d'`

Comment: @ChristianBongiorno `+10 days` as @steeldriver suggested works for me. What does your `date --version` say?

Comment: Bash isn't involved in the error.

Comment: For me, `date -d '2014-11-19T15:40:30 10 days'` works, `date -d '10 days'` works, `date -d '+10 days'` works, but `date -d '2014-11-19T15:40:30 +10 days' gives me the same thing as `date -d '2014-11-19T15:40:30 9 hours'. I'm not sure why. My date --version is 8.29.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$ docker run bash date --version
BusyBox v1.29.3 (2019-01-24 07:45:07 UTC) multi-call binary.
...
```

You are using the BusyBox version of `date` which is not fully compatible with the Coreutils version that can be found on most desktop Linux distros. Quoting BusyBox's man page:

```
Recognized TIME formats:

hh:mm[:ss]
[YYYY.]MM.DD-hh:mm[:ss]
YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm[:ss]
[[[[[YY]YY]MM]DD]hh]mm[.ss]
'date TIME' form accepts MMDDhhmm[[YY]YY][.ss] instead
```

Your possible options are:

- Use the BusyBox-exclusive `-D` key (e.g. `busybox date -D +10days`) which has extended support for time expressions similar to what Coreutils `date -d` has. Note that the option will not be recognized by the Coreutils `date`.
- Make do with the BusyBox syntax supported by both implementations.
- Install [Coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) in your Docker container.
- Use an existing container that has Coreutils.

Comment: I had just assumed that, date being as old as Earth, it would have identical support/functionality even on an alpine build.

Comment: It's even "worse" than that, BSD has its own version of `date` which is also [different](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?date)! I don't have much experience writing portable code on UNIX, but it seems you either have to target one specific flavour (for Linux, targeting GNU Coreutils should make most sense due to its relative ubiquity and user friendliness), or use the [POSIX subset of functionality](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/date.html) exclusively, hoping it would be supported by all implementations.