# awk: Add number of days to current date

Tags: text-processing, awk

By assigning the date to awk, I can get current date as following in yyyy-mm-dd:

```
awk -F, -v date="20$(date +%y-%m-%d)" '{print date}'
```

Output:

```
2019-02-17
```

Is there a way to add number of days to current date, let's say 7, so the output would be:

```
2019-02-24
```

Noting that using a method like below isn't providing the required output:

```
awk -F, -v date="20$(date +%y-%m-%d +7 days)" '{print date}'
```

Solution [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49053/linux-add-x-days-to-date-and-get-new-virtual-date) is not providing same date format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use format

```
date +%y-%m-%d --date="7 days"
```

to gate date after 7 days

And instead of adding 20 in front just use date on this way:

```
date=$(date +%Y-%m-%d --date="7 days")
```

Comment: How date formatted in yyyy-mm-dd?

Comment: Replace small "y" with caps "Y" and you will have 4 numbers year